# nginx/passenger rails app behind aws elb ssl don't load rails app on https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am running my rails 4 application with nginx/passenger server, and the SSL is on my AWS load balance. I forward port 443 to 80, but also I have port 80 to port 80..

The main idea is redirect all incoming and links from http to https. Just by adding the redirection on the load balance doesn't do the work.

Then I tried force_ssl on the production config on rails,  that didn't work either, because it shows me that the server is trying to look for the controller under the public folder.. and throw me a 404.

Another solution I was trying to do was adding this part on my sites-enabled/default file:

```
location / {
  # needed to forward user's IP address to rails
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;

  # needed for HTTPS
  proxy_set_header X-FORWARDED-PROTO https;

  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

}
```

That code above at least redirect the url to https but Nginx still show me the 404 code.
Without anything from above, and running through port 80, my application works.. and the front page that is pure html, it shows as https, but once I start using my rails application (going through my controllers), it goes back to http..
any suggestions, will be much appreciated.